# How to Change Secondary/Multi-line (>>) Prompt for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, prompt, multiline, ps2

I've found plenty of instructions for changing the primary PowerShell prompt (i.e. `prompt()`; *here is an example of one of the many helpful resources: http://blog.dabasinskas.net/customizing-windows-powershell-command-prompt/*) which is great, but I haven't been able to find anything concerning **how to change the secondary/multi-line prompt (`>>`),** or the Windows equivalent of the `$PS2` string on Linux/Unix systems.

Here is an example of a change,

```
[current_directory] $   `
>>
```

from **`>>`** to **`$`**

```
[current_directory] $   `
$
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For PowerShell 7, this is part of the [PSReadLine module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/?view=powershell-7).

```bsh
PS C:\> (Get-PSReadLineOption).ContinuationPrompt
>> 
PS C:\> Set-PSReadLineOption -ContinuationPrompt '~~ '
PS C:\> @'
~~
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the grave accent (or backtick):

```
PS C:\> Get-Service `
>> -name audiosrv
```

Comment: It seems you've misunderstood the question; I'm not asking how to _input_ multi-line content, but how to **change** the multi-line prompt string (**>>** by default) in Powershell.